# Should I play other Hitman games before playing Hitman: Absolution?

Tags: hitman-absolution

So... I just got Hitman: Absolution for PS3. I have started playing a few missions, but I feel like I am missing something.

Do I feel like I am missing something because I haven't played the other Hitman games OR of my failure to understand the story due to some other reason?

**Should I play the other Hitman games to understand the story?**

Comment: This isn't the type of question that has a yes or no answer for everyone. Try watching the film :)

Comment: @Meraj99 [Your question has been closed](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/close/32847). You could appeal that it be reopened or ask for a discussion on the closing of this question at [meta].

Comment: You should play all other previous games of hitman if you care about story. (which I think you are). I would have just played it for fun. Anyway, I played all the games of hitman. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer may be different for everyone but I am going to say no.  After you finish absolution, a lot of your questions will be answered [ I'm not going to provide those spoilers].  If you want some Hitman Lore, check out this very short video explaining some background to Agent 47

Comment: Otherwise, if something plot related has confused you - feel free to ask here ! Thats what we are here for.

Comment: One of the important things that video doesn't mention is who Diana is. She was your handler at the agency, she has been around since the first game, and is probably the closest thing 47 has to a friend. Which makes what happens at the beginning of Absolution quite significant.

Answer (score 2):

well its good to start with hitman codename 47 to get to know the story better or watch videos on the games

Answer (score 0):

Not really, but i do recommend you do play the other ones :)